# Can I define a struct whose objects will always be in separate cache lines

Tags: c++, c, caching, gcc, x86-64

I know that you can align variables to a cache line by using for example ***attribute**((align(64)))* in gcc. However, I'm interested in aligning (or you could call it padding) at structure declaration time. So for example, for the following *struct* I want to ask the compiler to create necessary padding so that any object of this structure is always aligned with a cache line.

```
typedef struct
{
 int a;
 int b;
 // I want the compiler to create a padding here for cache alignment
} my_type;
```

Comment: Add a big array of characters in the middle?..

Comment: Does this answer your question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1744407/cache-line-alignment-need-clarification-on-article ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Aligning to cache line and knowing the cache line size](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7281699/aligning-to-cache-line-and-knowing-the-cache-line-size)

Comment: Mat: That question is about aligning variables, here I'm talking about padding in a struct to make it align to the cache line, so its different!

Comment: i think gcc now supports #pragma [pack](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Structure_002dPacking-Pragmas.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. I can't remember where I got this code from.  I think it might have been Herb Sutter's blog:

```
    #define CACHE_LINE_SIZE 64 // Intel Core 2 cache line size.

    template<typename T>
    struct CacheLineStorage {

    public:

       [[ align(CACHE_LINE_SIZE) ]] T data;

    private:

       char pad[ CACHE_LINE_SIZE > sizeof(T)
            ? CACHE_LINE_SIZE - sizeof(T)
            : 1 ];
    };
```

Comment: Sutter's blog referenced here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1744407/cache-line-alignment-need-clarification-on-article

Comment: Why is there char pad[1] when CACHE_LINE_SIZE <= sizeof(T)? Ah maybe because you can't declare char pad[0] :)!

Comment: @user1018562 : What's the alternative? 0-length C-arrays are illegal.

Comment: Seems that 0 length arrays are perfectly legal in C++, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/295027/array-of-zero-length!

Comment: @user1018562 : That answer is wrong -- the C++ standard says otherwise (§8.3.4/1): "*If the constant-expression is present, it shall be an integral constant expression and its value shall be greater than zero.*"

Answer (score 2):

This is straightforward. You probably just missed the "ed" in `aligned`.

```
typedef struct
{
 int a __attribute__((aligned(64)));
 int b;

} my_type;
```

The resulting struct will have a 56 byte padding after b if you create variables or an array of it.

Comment: The question specifically was to make "any object of this structure is always aligned", so the attributes should be present for both members, making this 128 byte structure (on x86 in 64-bit mode at least).